# No. of ways for $(((n \mod i) \mod j) \mod k) \mod n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider $3$ integers, $i, j, k$ all between $1$ and $m$, both exclusive. Consider
$$(((n \mod i)\mod j)\mod k)\mod n$$
where $n$ is another positive integer. Suppose the maximum value of the above expression in $L$. Find the number of ways to choose the triple $(i,j,k)$ so as to get $L$.

My try:-

Since in the end we have $\mod n$, $L$ can be $n-1$ at max. But, the thing is if it can even achieve that value! For instance, if we take both $n$, $m$ to be $4$, I checked by hit and trial that $L$ will be $1$. This got me thinking, is there a general representation for these "concatenated" mods? I've no more idea on how to proceed. Even if a hint will do. Thanks :)

Comment: Do $i,j,k$ have to be different?

Comment: @TonyK no, there's no such condition on them

Answer (score 1):

A partial result in the case $n=m$.

Take $i=j=k=p$ where $p$ is the smallest integer greater than $n/2$. Then the result is $n-p$, the greatest integer lower than $n/2$.

Furthermore, if $i \geq p$, then $n$ mod $i$ is less than $n-i \leq n-p$ so the final result is kot greater than $n-p$.

If $i < p$, then $n$ mod $i$ is not greater than $p-1$ ($n$ odd) or $p-2$ ($p$ even) ie $n-p$.

A more careful study should yield the equality cases (I think it is $i=p,n-p$ and $j,k \geq n-p$).

Comment: Okay! And how about when n and m are not equal?

Comment: When $n < m$, we can choose $i=j=k=n$ and $L=n$. The rest is an exercise for you for now. ;)

Comment: Yeah I'm trying. But just for the record, $L=n$ is not possible, as I said that there's mod n in the end

Comment: Oh right, my mistake. Then I would say that when $m>n$ you cannot do better than when $m=n$ for pretty much the same reason. When $n > m$, I do not know yet.

Answer (score 0):

In every case the maximum remainder is N mod ((N/2)+1).
This will be the maximum value L.  Therefore L = N mod((N/2)+1)

Case 1: if N = M

Here i has to be (N/2)+1, because only that will yield remainder as L. If i has any other value, the remainder will always be less than L.
Now j,k should be 1 more than (N mod i) (so that the remainder remains L) till M.
Therefore j,k = (N mod i)+1 ...... M (Let this count be c)
hence total number of ways = c^2

Case 2: if M > N

Subcase 1: i = (N/2)+1 will give remainder as L
j,k = (N mod i)+1 ...... M (Let this count be c)
Total count = c^2

Subcase 2: j = (N/2)+1 but for this to happen we have to ensure that (N mod i) = N
Therefore to make N mod i = N , i = N+1 ...... M
k = (N mod j)+1 ...... M (Let this count be c)
Total count = (M-N)*c

Subcase 3: k = (N/2)+1 but for this to happen 
((N mod i) mod j) = N, Therefore i,j = N+1 ...... M
Total count = (M-N)^2

Hence total number of ways if M>N : c^2 + (M-N)*c + (M-N)^2